# PHPMyAdmin 404 error after install ffmpeg on Ubuntu 14.04 Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, phpmyadmin, vagrant

I have a development I have been working on for some time. It's running in Vagrant on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. PHPMyAdmin has been working fine for months accessible through `site.test:81`. Today I needed to install ffmpeg so as ffmpeg is no longer available for 14.04 I followed the instructions here https://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-04/

After installation, I verified that ffmpeg was installed and working. Then I went to make changes to the database through PHPMyAdmin and got a 404. It just isn't there any more! Why? And how can I get it back?

Comment: please, provide Vagrantfile and provision scripts which you are use.

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error or access logs?